# Power BI Report Builder portrait and landscape in the same document

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to split up a Power BI paginated report in Report Builder to have some pages in Portrait and others in Landscape (like a section break in Word) in order to fit more in where graphs and tables are needed.

Does anyone know if this is possible and how to set this up in Power BI Report Builder?